Show that the only solution of this ODE defined for $t=\pm 1$ is the zero function
I am currently a tutor for a course on differential equations. I have been presented with a solution for an exercise where I don't quite see, how the argument works. Concretely:
We are looking at the ODE
$$
(t^2-1)x'(t)+2t(x(t))^2=0
$$
and are searching for all the solutions. We first look for nonzero solutions defined on an interval not containing $\pm 1$. Separation of variables yields, that each such solution is of the form
$$
\varphi_c(t)=\frac{1}{\ln(|t^2-1|)+c}
$$
for some $c\in \mathbb R$.
Obviously $x\equiv 0$ is also a solution of the ODE. Now we look at a solution that is defined on an interval containing $t_0=1$. The given solution proceeds as follows: The ODE shows that $x(t_0)=0$. If we assume that $x$ is not locally the zero function around $t_0$, then $x$ takes nonzero values for some point $t_1$ arbitrarily close to $t_0$. However in this case $x$ must locally be of the form $\varphi_c(t)$, as the above argument shows. Since all of the functions $\varphi_c$ don't have any zeros, we arrive at a contradiction.
I cannot see how we arrive at a contradiction at this point. How does the local form of $x$ around $t_1$ contradict $x(t_0)=0$?
Thanks for any insights!


That's not what I am assuming and 2. all of the $\phi_c$ with $c\neq 0$ are continuous at $0$. What I am assuming is: We have an interval $I$ containing $1$ and a function $x\colon I\to \mathbb R$ satisfying the ODE. We wish to prove that $x\equiv 0$.


I think you mean $1$ when you speak of the origin. My problem in understanding is the following: Around some point arbitrarily close to $1$, $x$ has to take nonzero values and locally around that point be of the form $\phi_c$ for some $c$. However I still cannot see, how this contradicts anything.

The $\phi_c$ do not blow up. They converge to $0$ for $t\to 1$.

No, nvm I see what you mean. I was going by the comment you made below about blowing up to infinity, and didn't notice the term 'denominator' and combined with the graph below I just arrived at that conclusion without actually checking that for myself. Your point is well taken. Forget what I said.

Well, yeah. But we cannot just assume that $x=\phi_c$ on the entire interval. We only know this for some neighborhood of a point $t_1$ with $x(t_1)\neq 0$.

What do you mean by a solution? Does the solution need to be $C^1$?

@copper.hat So far in the course "solution" was supposed to be $C^1$.

If your solution is supposed to be $C^1$, wouldn't the intuition then be that if one expects there to be a non-trivial solution at $t = \pm 1$, it would have to be of the piecewise form in Robert's answer. But such a solution is not continuously differentiable at $t = \pm 1$.

Maybe that's what one would expect. However I don't find this a satisfying proof of the fact. All we really know is, that $x=\phi_c$ for some interval containing a point $t_1$ with $x(t_1)\neq 0$ arbitrarily close to $t_0$.

I believe one pieces the local solutions together using Picard-Lindelof, but at the moment, I don't have the means to produce a formal proof.

Yeah, I was also thinking about something along those lines. Whatever a proof of this fact will look like, I think we can agree that the solution that was presented to me is incomplete at best.

Let $I_- = (-\infty,-1), I=(-1,1), I_+ = (1,\infty)$. I assume that you are looking for a $C^1$ solution.
It is clear that the zero function satisfies the ODE on any interval.
Picard Lindelöf (and a little reasoning) shows that for any $t_0,x_0$ with $|t_0| \neq 1$, there is a unique solution defined on the above interval that contains $t_0$ (call the interval $J$ for definiteness).
If, in addition, if $|x_0| \neq 0$, then it is clear that the solution on $J$ is given by $\phi_c$ for some $c$. Let $b$ be a boundary point of $J$ (which must be $\pm 1$), then we see that $\lim_{t \to b, b \in J} |\phi'(t)| = \infty$. In particular, the solution cannot be extended to an interval containing the boundary point.

Thanks for your answer. Picard-Lindelöf is not available to the students yet, so this doesn't fix the proposed solution. As I did not specify in my OP, that Picard-Lindelöf cannot be used, I will accept your answer. In the meantime I also found a solution that does not use Picard-Lindelöf.

[EDITED]
Actually separation of variables says that
$$ \dfrac{x'(t)}{x(t)^2} = \frac{-2t}{t^2-1} $$
but only if $x(t) \ne 0$ and $t^2 \ne 1$.  The differential equation itself
tells you that when $t = \pm 1$, $2 t x(t)^2 = 0$, so $x(t) = 0$.  The solution $x(t) = 0$ happens to be a global solution.  The "general" solutions
$x(t) = \frac{1}{\ln|t^2-1| + c}$ are undefined at $t = \pm 1$;  they happen to go to $0$ in the limit as $t \to \pm 1$. If you wish, you might consider $$ x(t) = \cases{\frac{1}{\ln|t^2-1| + c} & if $t^2 \ne 1$\cr
0 & if $t^2 = 1$\cr} $$
as a "solution", but note that at $t = \pm 1$ you don't really have a differential equation (and certainly not a differential equation satisfying the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem).  You could even use different $c$'s for $t < -1$, $-1 < t < 1$ and $t > 1$.

How are the solutions $\varphi_c(t)$ blowing up for $t\to\pm 1$? The denominator goes to $-\infty$ afterall.

Oops: correcting...

Thanks for the correction. However I don't see how this adresses my question. I want to understand the argument, that any solution of the ODE also defined for $t=\pm 1$ has to be the zero function. I have outlined the argument presented to me in my original post.

I recommend drawing graphs for additional understanding.  The first one is with $x(\sqrt 2 )$ positive, actually 2. Run time backwards, it blows up    as the denominator becomes zero.

The second has $x(\sqrt 2 )$ negative

The blowup behavior is identical.

Thanks for your answer. However also with your answer I don't see the connection to my question. We assume we have a solution $x(t)$ of the ODE defined on some (possibly small) interval containing $t_0=1$. The claim is, that $x\equiv 0$.

@NicoZimmer  What does it mean to say $\frac{1}{\ln(|t^2-1|)+c} = 0  ; ; ? ; ;  $

Of course there are no solutions for this equation. That's my point / question: What does this fact have to do with my question?
